# The print of while loop into text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I've done this in python. When I insert a word, it'll repeated with after a digit
For Example if I insert stack, it-ll print:

```
stack 1
stack 2
stack 3
stack 4
stack 5
stack 6
stack 7
stack 8
stack 9
```

I want that python to print the name and the digit in a file text. I searches but didn't find anything.

Code:

```
pwd=raw_input("Enter a word:")
n=0
n=str(n)
print (pwd,n)
while n<9:
  out_file=open("tesxt.txt","w")
  n+=1
  out_file.write(pwd)
  out_file.write(n)
out_file.close()
```

I want that python to write the words that are generated from the loop.
Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

First in Python 2.7 print is used without the bracket:

```
>>> print "hello world"
hello world
```

Then you should open the file outside the `while` loop.

```
out_file = open("test.txt", "w")
i = 0
while n < 9:
   # do something here  

out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in redefining n. You start with n as an integer (`n = 0`), then turned it into a string (`n = str(n)`).

Try this:

```
pwd = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
n = 0
print("{} {}".format(pwd, n))
with open("test.txt", "w") as out:
    while n < 9:
        out.write("{} {}\n".format(pwd, n))
        n += 1
```

That should give you the output you expect, because you never redefine n.
If you want to be both python 2 and 3 compliant, add `from __future__ import print_statement` to the top of the script, which will allow your print() call to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors:

1. You try to += 1 on a `str` object. That's a no-no.
2. You open a file several times without closing it.

Try taking advantage of the context manager that `open` uses with a while loop inside. Something like this:

```
pwd = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
with open("tesxt.txt", "w") as fout:
    n = 0
    while n <= 9:  # this will print 0-9. without the =, it will print 0-8
        data = "{} {}".format(pwd, n)
        print(data)
        fout.write("{}\n".format(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

pwd = raw_input('Enter a word:')
n = 0
print pwd, n
with open('tesxt.txt','w') as out_file:

    while n < 9 :
         n += 1
         out_file.write('{} {}\n'.format(pwd, n))

Comment: And if I wanted put an list of name... How can I do? I'am a beginner in python